# Add Control to ASP.NET Web Page with runatserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Use this method in into a Page

```
 private HiddenField idHiddenField = new HiddenField();
 public void SetIdToHiddenField(string id)
    {
        idHiddenField.ID = "IdHiddenField";
        idHiddenField.Value = id;

        Page.Controls.Add(idHiddenField);
    }
```

I want to create a HiddenField Dynamically into my page and store anything
but when use this method an error occures

```
Control 'IdHiddenField' of type 'HiddenField' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

How can i add a hiddenfield dynamically without any problem ?

Comment: whats a datagridview in asp.net? please be more elaborate to get correct answers

Comment: datagridview = asp.net Gridview , I changed text of my question

Comment: datagridview is a winforms control fyi. please post the relevant markup and elaborate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for hidden fields, ASP.NET allows you to do the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerhiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx

specifically for your example:

```
public void SetIdToHiddenField(string id)
{
Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("idHiddenField", id);
}
```

Comment: The code I provided was just for reference. I updated my answer to show all you would have to do.

Comment: How get value of this Hiddenfield into usercontrol or another location ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by placing your hiddenfield in a specific location? I also updated my answer because Page.RegisterHiddenField is deprecated.

Comment: I needed a server side control so I used HtmlInputHidden and problem solved :D

Answer (score 0):

the exception says clearly, the form of your page must have `runat` property, like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
```

does it have `runat` property ?

Comment: I have masterpage and my masterpage have form with runatserver

Comment: so why don't you add the `HiddenField` to the `ContentPlaceHolder` ?